# Convert a multi value dictionary to a Dataframe in python

Tags: python, string, nlp

The dictionary

```
{'password': ['Input data fields to enter - 1) Username 2) Password 3) Re-enter Password 4) Security question 5) Security answer\nUsername data field specifications - At least one uppercase, \nUsername data field specifications - At least one lowercase.',

  'Password data field specifications - At least 7 characters, \nPassword data field specifications - 1 number, \nPassword data field specifications - 1 uppercase letter, \nPassword data field specifications - 1 lowercase letter, \nPassword data field specifications - one special charactersss.',
  'Password criteria should be displayed to the user when user clicks inside the password data field.',
  "Green check mark next to 'Password' data field should be displayed that indicates to the user after typing password that the entry meets criteria.",
  "Red cross mark next to 'Password' data field should be displayed that indicates to the user after typing password that the entry does not meet criteria.",
  "Validate that inputs in 'Password' and 'Re-enter Password' data fields match- Green check mark next to 'Re-enter' password data field should be displayed that indicates to the user after typing if passwords match\n'Password' and 'Re-enter Password' entries should be masked.",
  'Password entries will show the keystroke typed, and then after two seconds the entered character is masked.',
  'If \'Password\' entry does not match criteria specified and user hits Submit, show error alert "Password entry does not meet criteria".',
  "If entries in 'Password' and 'Re-enter Password' do not match and user hits Submit, show error alert 'Password entries do not match'."]}
```

Needed to a data-frame by converting these list of values into a DF with same key

Comment: What's the expected output? Could you please include the code you tried writing yourself? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure about what you want but

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame('Your dictionary comes here')
```

Additionally:
If you have just an array and you need to put it into a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame() # Without any arguments
dataframe['The Coulmn name'] = 'Your array comes here'
```

Comment: Please, give me more information about your desired output.

Comment: I want to have the dictionary to be something like this they key (password) and the values i the list as in the second column in the adjascent to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your desired out put, may be you wanted something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'password': ['Input data fields to enter - 1) Username 2) Password 3) Re-enter Password 4) Security question 5) Security answer\nUsername data field specifications - At least one uppercase, \nUsername data field specifications - At least one lowercase.',

  'Password data field specifications - At least 7 characters, \nPassword data field specifications - 1 number, \nPassword data field specifications - 1 uppercase letter, \nPassword data field specifications - 1 lowercase letter, \nPassword data field specifications - one special charactersss.',
  'Password criteria should be displayed to the user when user clicks inside the password data field.',
  "Green check mark next to 'Password' data field should be displayed that indicates to the user after typing password that the entry meets criteria.",
  "Red cross mark next to 'Password' data field should be displayed that indicates to the user after typing password that the entry does not meet criteria.",
  "Validate that inputs in 'Password' and 'Re-enter Password' data fields match- Green check mark next to 'Re-enter' password data field should be displayed that indicates to the user after typing if passwords match\n'Password' and 'Re-enter Password' entries should be masked.",
  'Password entries will show the keystroke typed, and then after two seconds the entered character is masked.',
  'If \'Password\' entry does not match criteria specified and user hits Submit, show error alert "Password entry does not meet criteria".',
  "If entries in 'Password' and 'Re-enter Password' do not match and user hits Submit, show error alert 'Password entries do not match'."]})

print df
```

Output:

```
    password
0   Input data fields to enter - 1) Username 2) Pa...
1   Password data field specifications - At least ...
2   Password criteria should be displayed to the u...
3   Green check mark next to 'Password' data field...
4   Red cross mark next to 'Password' data field s...
5   Validate that inputs in 'Password' and 'Re-ent...
6   Password entries will show the keystroke typed...
7   If 'Password' entry does not match criteria sp...
8   If entries in 'Password' and 'Re-enter Passwor
```

Comment: I want the first column to the key and the value which are in the list

Comment: Can you share me the code of what you have done as well?

Comment: You wanted a Datafrme like this, I guess!!

Comment: Just share a sample of the output you want!

Comment: Password   --------   'Password data field specifications - At least 7 characters, 
                                \nPassword  data field specifications - 1 number, \nPassword 
                                 data field 
                       specifications - 
                      1 uppercase letter, \nPassword data field specifications - 1 lowercase 
                      letter, \nPassword data field specifications - one special charactersss.'